# Point of time in a week

Tags: java, datetime, date, time

Is there a simple way to store points of time relative to days of a week and not an exact date  in Java (e.g. Monday 11:00 pm instead of Monday, May 23st 2011, 11:00 pm)?

Of course it would be a nice feature to have a comparision with another given "complete" date and time, so that I can determine if it is "equal" to the point of time mentioned above (e.g. Monday 11:00 pm is equal to Monday, May 23st 2011, 11:00 pm).

Comment: For the sake of data integrity, why not store the time in its entirety and format it relatively on display?

Comment: I need it for an application which stores opening hours which are entered by an user. That might not be very convenient then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend checking out the [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) open source library.  It doesn't have anything right out of the box that does exactly what you want, but you should be able to write a custom extension to the Partial class that tracks a day of week and time.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's anything built in to do that, but it shouldn't be too hard to build your own.

Since the date doesn't matter, how about setting a constant date as a starting point and the times will be relevant to that point?  Just drop the actual date for display purposes.  That way all the build-in date calculations work out correctly.

You can (should) encapsulate the behavior in a class, so that the fact that a full date is stored is an implementation detail.